# need help please! Changed base link now unable to enter magento 1.8 and actual website

Tags: magento-1.8

I went into system then configuration then web and I changed the base url in the secure and unsecure section....originally it had {{base_url}} but then I changed it to the new website name and now I cant get in at all. I cant even get into Magento!Please help!!

Comment: No. Im a totally different person and need help.

Comment: its about the question, we are a question/answer community, not a support forum.
Did you try all answers from the link?

Comment: As I said in my question...I cant even get into magento now and dont know if I need to get into the ftp

Comment: The web developer left....this is new information to me

Answer (score 0):

Please try to follow approach from this page
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/recover/restore_base_url_settings

It will help to restore your base URL on the database level.